# How do I avoid getting a memory error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, out-of-memory

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\modular inverse.py", line 12, in <module>
    Multiples_of_e.append(e*f)
MemoryError
```

This is the code :

```
Multiples_of_e = []

e=input("Enter the exponent: ")

f=1

for i in range(100000):
    Multiples_of_e.append(e*f)
    f+=1
```

If I remove these two lines

```
e=input("Enter the exponent: ")
totent=input("Enter the totent: ")
```

And I just replace each variable with its value inside the code the problem gets solved, is there anyway to make this work without doing that ?

Comment: The problem is clearly in the first loop, as indicated by the error message. The second loop is irrelevant, remove it from the question. Also remove `totent=input("Enter the totent: ")` and `foundit=False` for the same reason. Now, what is the value of `e` that you enter?

Comment: The value of e I usually put is 65537 but even though it's large the program works as long as I remove the line of code e=input("Enter the exponent: ")

Comment: If you insert a simple `print` command to trace your values, you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to convert the input to an integer number. Your loop multiplies strings.